# Determine whether the following relation is an equivalence relation

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Determine whether the following relation B on A is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive.
>   $$A=\{1,2,3\}$$
>   $$B = \{(1,1),(1,3),(3,2)\}$$

These are my guesses, because the textbook only showed an example between relations between elements in a single set, not elements between two sets.

Would these both be partitions of $\mathbb{Z}$? I want to say no because of the type of elements (i.e. 1 vs (1,1)). However I tried to treat them as such when approaching this problem.

- The relation is not reflexive since $(2,2)$ and $(3,3)$ are not in $B$.
- The relation is not symmetric since $(1,3)$ and $(3,2)$ are in $B$, but $(3,1)$ and $(2,3)$ are not in $A$.
- I am unsure how to show the transitive relationship between the two sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation is unclear: is $A$ a set and $B$ a relation on $A$? Is it meant to indicate that two elements $a$ and $b$ are "related" if the pair $(a,b)$ belongs to $B$?

In that case you are right that it is neither reflexive nor symmetric.

For transitivity, you need to check that if $(a,b)\in B$ and $(b,c)\in B$, then $(a,c)\in B$. But this is false: take $a=1$, $b=3$, and $c=2$.

Good luck!

EDIT: Here is why I think the notation is unclear.

1. A set's elements should be enclosed in curly braces: so instead of
   saying $A=1,2,3$, you should write $A=\{1,2,3\}$. This is the
   standard notation for sets.
2. You said "the following relation" and proceeded to list two sets, only one of which was a relation. You should say "let $A$ be
   the set $\{1,2,3\}$, and let $B$ be the following relation on $A$:
   ..." When I first read your post, I thought $A$ and $B$ were both supposed to be relations, and I hesitated before realizing what you meant.
3. The notation is a little unusual. You wouldn't say "let $a$ be a real number, and let $b$ be a function" --- it's strange to use alphabetically-near letters to represent completely different objects. You can use $A$ to denote the base set, but then you should use a letter like $R$ for the relation.

Comment: hmm yes actually, B is a relation on set A. How can I make the notation more clear? edit: made a slight change to notation that I think will help

Comment: Good question! There are a few reasons why it's unclear and unusual. I will edit my answer to include them.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Back to checking for transitivity, $(1,3) \in B$, $(3,2) \in B$, but $(1,2)$ is NOT in $B$.

Answer (score 1):

Your doing fine with your answers so far. For transitivity you have to check whether or not the following is true:
if $(a,b)$ and $(b,c)$ are in $B$ , then $(a,c)$ is there as well.

Now just look!

As to partitions, they certainly do not fill up all of $\mathbb{Z}$ and I think you  may need to get what a partition is a bit clearer in your mind.  $A$ is a set with $B$ specifying the subset of $A\times A$ that gives the relation, so if anything was going to be partitioned it would be $A$. The example is of a single set, and not between two   different sets.

Comment: so by $(a,b)$, we can think of $a \rightarrow b$ where $a$ is the input and $b$ is the output?

Comment: @Evan Kim: I would suggest the notation $aBb$ to be read as '$a$ is related to $b$' in the relation $B$. That is verbose but is necessary as $B$ in the question is given as the relation. I would have written $R$ simply because relation starts with an R!!  If you want to draw the graph of the relation it is a three by three array with three squares with x in them. (Difficult to do that neatly here without thought!)

Comment: I will have a go: I will write 1 if that place is in the relation and 0 otherwise.     First row 100, next 001, last 100. I can help to view the properties on such a graph. For example, reflexivity corrspond to the diagonal (bottom left to top right) being in the relation.